# php first letter uppercase

Tags: php

I have this echo:

```
<?=$item['Field']?>
```

I'm trying to get every 1st letter capitalized.

I tried this

```
<?$item = ucwords(strtolower('Field'));?>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you explain more? Provide the string you are trying to do this to?

Comment: Is it just a typo?  Do you mean `<?=ucwords(strtolower($item['Field']));?>`

Comment: What kind of input are you expecting? Does it all follow the same format?

Answer (score 4):

Try that:

```
<?$item_capitalize = ucwords(strtolower($item['Field']));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want one of the following

```
<?= $item[ucwords(strtolower('Field'))]; ?>
<?= ucwords(strtolower($item['Field'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it, don't assign it.

```
<?=ucwords(strtolower($item['Field']));?>
```